# Summing each year for each grouped in grouped series

Tags: python, for-loop, group-by

I have a dataset of protected areas that I have grouped by each country's ISO3 code. What I want to do is sum the amount of protected areas for each country by the year they were established (STATUS_YR). The goal is to get one dataframe where it gives a country and for each year the number of protected areas established for that year. My code dosen't work and I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I think I need to do a for loop where it uses the ISO3 as a key and takes the number of instances of each year and sums them, I've used the Len() function but it didn't work.

Code:

```
protected_areas = pd.DataFrame()

columns = ["STATUS_YR"]


for key, group in wdpa4_grouped:
    column = len(group[columns])
    
    column["ISO3"] = key
    
    row = column.to_frame().transpose()
    
    protected_areas = pd.concat([protected_areas, row], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wdpa_grouped = wdpa4.groupby(['ISO3', 'STATUS_YR'])['STATUS_YR'].count()
```

Group by each country and for each country each year, then count the number for each year.